# OBS on Ubuntu 16.04 captures only mouse pointer

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, obs-studio

I am using OBS (Open Broadcaster Software) in Ubuntu 16.04.

While Selecting `Screen Capture(XSHM)` in sources I am able to capture the screen.

While Selecting `Window Capture(Xcomposite)` in sources  it is capturing only mouse pointer with a black background.

How to resolve this issue. ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue.

If you double click `Window Capture(Xcomposite)` below screen will appear.

[image]

In this page if you scroll down you will get `Use alpha-less texture format(Mesa workaround)` option you have to check that box.

Solved using [this](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/solved-window-capture-black-screen.47082/) post.

Comment: This just makes the capture black instead of transparent for me.